# Using RegExpressions to validate GPA

Tags: javascript, regex

So i have to validate the gpa being entered so that it follows the guidelines first number is 0-4 the next thing is a (.) followed by 2 more digits 0-9.  This is what i have but it is not working.

```
function validateGPA(gpa){
        var errorValue = gpa;
        var legalValue = /^\[0-4]\[.]\d\d$/;
        console.log(gpa);
        if(gpa == ""){
            errorValue = "Please enter your GPA.\n";
        }   else if(!legalValue.test(gpa)){
            errorValue = "Please enter a 3 digit gpa.\n";
        }
        return errorValue;
    }
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong, Ive tried a few tweaks but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Why are you escaping `[`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the shortest expression:

```
/^[0-4]\.\d\d$/
```

Explanation:

```
^     - Start of line
[0-4] - One digit in the range 0-4
\.    - A dot, which needs to be escaped with a backslash.
        Without the backslash it means "any character apart from line break"
\d\d  - Two digits (any value from 0-9)
$     - End of line
```

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
/^[0-4]\.\d{2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-4][.][0-9][0-9]$/
```

^ matches all strings starting with a number between 0 and 4
$ - Means the string ends with a number from 0 to 9

Hope this helps.